# Null pointer in textview

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

I'm new on Android and I'm trying to do my first app.

I've read a lot of posts here about the same problem I got, but couldn't figure it out.

I hope you can help me.

My app has several Activities. In this case in particular, I'm sending a string which I want to put in a textview. When I tried to do this, the app crashed. So, I read a lot of posts and "catched" the null pointer. But that meant my setContentView is not working.

I'm working with ADT downloaded on 2014-06-21.
Tried to clean Eclipse, but it remains the same.
Tried to change the name of tvGrupo (before, it was textView1).

Also, I'm not very good at english, as you can tell and more important, since I'm new in Android I'm not use to all the words used commonly to describe process... :(
So, please be very specific.

Thanks for all the help!

This is my code:

```
public class DisplayGrup extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_grup);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    TextView tvgrupo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGrupo);
    if (tvgrupo == null) {
// this is how i know i received a null pointer.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Puntero nulo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        tvgrupo.setText("hola");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Obteniendo dato:" + tvgrupo.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_grup, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_grup,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

public void clickBorrar(View view) {
        // This works just fine.
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGrupo);
    tv.setText("hhhh");
}
}
```

This is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mula_saltadora.DisplayGrup$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="clickBorrar"
        android:text="Borrar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGrupo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Grupo"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Agregar" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvGrupo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvGrupo"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText1"
         >
    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your textview is in fragment layout so put your code in onCreateView instead in onCreate:

```
View rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_grup,
            container, false);

    TextView tvgrupo = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvGrupo);
    if (tvgrupo == null) {
        // this is how i know i received a null pointer.
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Puntero nulo", 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        tvgrupo.setText("hola");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Obteniendo dato:" + 
             tvgrupo.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return rootView;
}

public void clickBorrar(View view) {
    // This works just fine.
    TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvGrupo);
    tv.setText("hhhh");
}
```

**Edit:**
Change getApplicationContext() to getActivity() and make rootView global variable in fragment and use it in function clickBorrar too. See edited code.

Comment: On findViewById, I got: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity.
On getApplicationContext, I got: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplicationContext() from the type ContextWrapper

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make your **rootView** accessible to all your fragment, and use it to call **findViewById**. Its something like this:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    View rootView;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_grup,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

public void clickBorrar(View view) {
        // This works just fine.
    TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvGrupo);
    tv.setText("hhhh");
}
}
```

Comment: Gracias Pedro! Zoltan me dio una respuesta similar que ya me funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, In your activity cannot have textview, so you cannot call findViewById. so you must call rootView caused Fragment.
e.g : 
in activity findViewByID....... 
in fragment rootView......

or outside rootView if you using fragment you can using getView().